# Excel and Python: Merge + Append multiple workbooks with multiple worksheets

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm not entirely sure where to start with this project, and with the, albeit limited, research that I've done, I haven't come across the correct answer or methodology to use.

I have two excel workbooks, with multiple worksheets(tabs). I'm trying to merge/append them into a single excel sheet with the following logic:

Workbook A = main worksheet
Workbook B = secondary worksheet
Column A in all worksheets are the "index" - Datetime format

- Open A
- Open B
- For each worksheet in B, check to see if it exists in A
  --- If it does exist, check the following:
  ------ if index exists, don't add
  ------ if index does not exist, add to the worksheet
  --- If it doesn't exist, add a new worksheet to A
- Save worksheet A
- Delete worksheet B (if everything works)

Answer (score 0):

After commenting my logic, here is the answer:

```
import pandas as pd

masterPath = 'data/TrainingData.xlsx'
tempPath = 'data/WatchList - 2020-07-22 16-50.xlsx'

masterBook = pd.ExcelWriter(masterPath, engine='openpyxl')
tempBook = pd.ExcelWriter(tempPath, engine='openpyxl')

masterSheetNames = pd.ExcelFile(masterPath).sheet_names
tempSheetNames = pd.ExcelFile(tempPath).sheet_names

for sheetName in tempSheetNames:
    if sheetName in masterSheetNames:
        df_m = pd.read_excel(masterBook,
                             index_col=None,
                             na_values=['NA'],
                             sheet_name=sheetName)
        
        df_t = pd.read_excel(tempBook,
                             index_col=None,
                             na_values=['NA'],
                             sheet_name=sheetName)
        df_t.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
        df_m.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
        
        df = pd.concat([df_m, df_t], axis = 0, ignore_index=True)
        df.drop_duplicates(subset=('Date'), keep='first', inplace=True)
        df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
        
        df_t.to_excel(masterBook, sheet_name = sheetName)
        
    else:
        print(sheetName + ' will be added to Main doc')
        df_t = pd.read_excel(tempBook,
                             index_col=None,
                             na_values=['NA'],
                             sheet_name=sheetName)
        df_t.drop_duplicates(subset=('Date'), keep='first', inplace=True)
        df_t.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
        df_t.to_excel(masterBook, sheet_name = sheetName)

masterBook.save()
masterBook.close()
```